# Import error while running python scripts inside a directory?

Tags: python

I have directory which has a app and it has corresponding test script files in 'tests' directory.

```
project/
--myapp/
--__init__.py(<-- updated)
--tests/
  --tests1.py
  --tests2.py etc
--run_tests.py
```

`runtests.py` traverses 'tests' directory recursively and executes all python scripts in it.

`tests*.py` has to import myapp for the tests to run. Since, `tests*.py` files are in 'tests' directory, it doesn't work.

How do I make 'myapp' to be available to all `tests*.py` files in 'tests' directory? I think there would be simple solution than setting 'myapp' in PYTHONPATH.

Note: `nosetests tests/` will work. So, just curious on how it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `myapp` is in pythonpath:

```
from myapp import mymodule
```

You can also do relative imports:

```
from .. import mymodule
```

Comment: Hey..sorry \_\_init\_\_.py is there in 'myapp' directory, otherwise even app will not work.:) And 'myapp' is not there in pythonpath. My question is 'nosetests tests/' will work. why not 'python runtests.py'

Comment: added example for relative imports to my answer, does that help you?

Comment: Tried 'from .. import myapp', got error ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package.

Comment: From what file are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a feature that makes a directory a package (**init**.py). With that, each .py file becomes a part of this module.

try checking this post

[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Sorry.. I haven't mentioned \_\_init\_\_.py in question, but it is there, without that app will not work!:)